# Hermitian form of a unitary space

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, quadratic-forms

If $V$ is a finite $n$-dimensional complex vector space with a hermitian form $h$ then $h$ is given by a hermitian matrix $A$ with the transformation law $P^{t}A\bar{P}$ where $P$ is an invertible $n\times n$ matrix and $^\bar{}$ denotes complex conjugation.

> If $V$ is unitary, in other words $h$ is positive definite, then why must $P$ be a unitary matrix?

Many thanks!

Comment: What does "transformation law" mean? I think the question you meant to ask and the question you actually asked are not the same.

Comment: Do you mean to ask why $A$ must be a unitary matrix?  What is your preferred definition of a unitary matrix?

Comment: @Cameron Williams- by the transformation law I mean how the matrix of the form $h$ transforms under a change of basis for $V$.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom  No, I really mean $P$ not $A$. For me, $P$ is unitary if $P^HP=I$ where $^H$ is Hermitian conjugation. This question came up while reading Cohn's Classic Algebra, Chapter 11, page 341 where he just states the result as above without giving proof.

Comment: @Eddie well, what does it mean for $V$ to be unitary?  Do you mean that $h(x,y) = \langle x,y \rangle$ for all $x,y \in V$?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom sorry the question was badly worded. I meant a unitary space to be a finite dimensional complex vector space with a positive definite hermitian form. I've now corrected the mistake.

Comment: The statement as you've written it doesn't seem to be true.  $V$ is unitary if and only if $A$ is positive definite.  If $A$ is positive definite, $P^TA\overline{P}$ will be positive definite for any invertible $P$.